Why is Sidney apologizing for the press feature about Steve?
Susie and Steve were having a private moment behind the club, which was interrupted by Sidney,
a press agent. Sidney asked about some glossy prints, but Steve suggested forgetting about them:

Steve: Come on, Susie. It's cold out here.
Sidney: Let me apologize for getting you a press spread. It's been an
honor serving you gratis!

Why is Sidney apologizing for the press feature about Steve?

This is an example of sarcasm.
Context: Sidney has agreed to publicise this young guitar player on behalf of the club owner. Sidney and Steve's relationship is complicated by the fact that Steve thinks that Sidney has some sort of ulterior motive in hanging around the club, spying on him and Susie. The guitar player decides to give Sidney the brush off. He doesn't want or need his help, he claims.
Sidney is apologising sarcastically for having wasted his time by getting him into the newspapers and helping to improve his career. The sarcasm is due to the fact that Steve should be grateful, rather than ungrateful, for the effort that Sidney has put in, even if it means a little bit of extra work for Steve.
